# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mano')

Tags: javascript, typeerror, undefined

when I was programming a website with JS, accidentally appears an Uncaught type error, I made all for "fighting" this error but It happened nothing

EDIT: which line would cause it?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mano')<br>
    at scambiaCarta (script.js:496:16)<br>
    at eseguiTurnoCPU (script.js:369:9)<br>
    at gestisciTurni (script.js:256:9)<br>
    at iniziaGioco (script.js:230:5)<br>
    at script.js:221:9
```

```
function creaGiocatore(nome) {
    return {
        nome: nome,
        vite: 3,
        mano: []
    };
}

function eseguiTurnoCPU() {
    const giocatoreCorrente = giocatori[turnoCorrente % giocatori.length];
    const giocatorePrecedente = giocatori[(turnoCorrente - 1 + giocatori.length)];

    if (deveScambiareCarta(giocatoreCorrente)) {
        scambiaCarta(giocatoreCorrente, giocatorePrecedente);
    } else {
        console.log(`${giocatoreCorrente.nome} decide di non scambiare la carta.`);
    }

    turnoCorrente = (turnoCorrente + 1) % giocatori.length;
    setTimeout(gestisciTurni, 2000);
}

function scambiaCarta(giocatore1, giocatore2) {
    if (deveBloccareScambioCarta(giocatore1.mano[0])) {
        console.log(`${giocatore1.nome} ha il Re in mano. Cucù.`);
        return;
    }

    const index1 = giocatori.indexOf(giocatore1);
    const index2 = giocatori.indexOf(giocatore2);


    const cartaScambiata = giocatore1.mano.splice(0, 1)[0];
    giocatore2.mano.push(cartaScambiata);


    const cartaScambiata2 = giocatore2.mano.splice(0, 1)[0];
    giocatore1.mano.push(cartaScambiata2);


    aggiornaCarte(giocatore1, index1);
    aggiornaCarte(giocatore2, index2);

    console.log(`${giocatore1.nome} ha scambiato una carta con ${giocatore2.nome}.`);
    mostraCarte();
}

function iniziaGioco() {
    console.log('Il gioco è iniziato!')
    inizializzaConsole();
    aggiornaConsoleVite();

    gestisciTurni();
    mostraCarte();
    aggiornaCarte();
}

function gestisciTurni() {
    const giocatoreCorrente = giocatori[turnoCorrente % giocatori.length];

    if (giocatoreCorrente.vite === 0) {
        turnoCorrente = (turnoCorrente + 1) % giocatori.length;
        setTimeout(() => {

            gestisciTurni();
        }, 2000);
        return;
    }
 
    if (turnoCorrente === 0) {
        mostraPulsantiUtente();
    } else {
        nascondiPulsantiUtente();
        eseguiTurnoCPU();
    }
    if (turnoCorrente === iMazziere) {
        eseguiTurnoMazziere();
    }
    turnoCorrente = (turnoCorrente + 1) % giocatori.length;
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Answer (score 0):

`mano` is ***returned*** as part of an object from `function creaGiocatore`. It's not a property of `creaGiocatore`. In order to be able to use it, you need to *invoke* the function, like this: `let result = creaGiocatore("some nome")`. Then you can do: `result.mano[0] ...`.

Here's an example:

```js
function creaGiocatore(nome) {
    return {
        nome: nome,
        vite: 3,
        mano: [1,2,3]
    };
}

// You have to invoke the function to recieve its return value
let result = creaGiocatore("foo");

// Then you can use the return value
console.log(result.mano);
```